# Is there any benefit in using Map (Object) over objects in React functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I couldn't find anything about this online but I recently saw some React examples using the [Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to make a simple mapper.  This had me wondering if there is some kind of benefit to using the Map object rather than a plain javascript object {} in React functional components.

Are there any noteworthy difference between these two examples?

```
function myFunctionalComponent() {
    const mapper = {
        foo: 'bar',
        fizz: 'buzz'
    };
}

function myFunctionalComponent() {
    const mapper = new Map([
        ['foo', 'bar',],
        ['fizz', 'buzz']
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential advantage of a Map is that its keys can be of any type - unlike plain objects, in which a key may only be a string or a symbol. Something else to consider is that plain objects with dynamic keys can rarely be problematic due to property name collisions (`__proto__`, `valueOf`, etc).

That said, in React, a Map probably isn't that great of an idea:

- In React, state should never be mutated, but if you use a Map, you'll probably be very tempted to use methods like `Map.set` - which mutates it. You'll have to remember to clone the map first every time.

  You won't be able to do

  ```
  setState({ ...stateObj, [prop]: newVal })
  ```

  but instead

  ```
  setState(new Map(stateMap).set(prop, newVal))
  ```
- Iterating through Maps is somewhat cumbersome because the only way to do so is through their iterators (`.entries`, `.keys`, `.values`) - but iterators aren't arrays and can't be `.map`ped to JSX immediately. Every time you want to do something with the Map, you'd have to turn it into an array instead: `[...myMap.entries()].map((key, value) =>` which is a bit ugly.
- If dynamic keys are something to worry about, you can use an array instead: `const mapper = [{ key: 'foo', value: 'bar' } ...` without having to use a Map.

It's not that a Map *can't* be implemented properly, or that a plain object can't either - you just have to be careful.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response! I figured there wouldn't be much noticeable difference in terms of React.  These are all very insightful points, thank you.

Comment: DV because this response fails to make a meaningful comparison to plain objects. Both are mutable. Neither has an array-like `map` function. If anything, `for (const [k, v] of myMap)` and `[...myMap].map(...)` are less "ugly" and "cumbersome" than `for (const [k,v] of Object.entries(myMap))` and `Object.entries(myMap).map(...)`.